# Instantiate generic object from type of

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I found this code to instantiate a new object T with a parameter :

```
create<T>(type: { new(p: any): T }, val: any): T {
    return new type(val);
  }
```

My goal is to have a base class which I can inherit to init my array properties :

```
export class Base {
  create<T>(type: { new(p: any): T }, val: any): T {
    return new type(val);
  }

  init<T>(propertyArray: T[], input: any): void {
    if (propertyArray == null) {
      propertyArray = [];
      for (let i in input) {
        let tmpObj = this.create(T, i);
        propertyArray.push(tmpObj);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
class A extends Base {

  private _prop: B[];

  get prop() {
    return this._prop;
  }
  set prop(value: any) {
    this.init(this._prop, value);
  }

  constructor(obj: any) {
    super(obj);
    this.prop = obj && obj.item || null;
  }
}
```

But in this sample `let tmpObj = this.create(T, i);` I get this error :

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How can I correct this to work ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the rest of your code is supposed to work, but you have to pass in a *constructor* of a type to be able to construct an instance of the type.

---

Let's examine the signature of the `create()` function:

```
declare function create<T>(type: { new(p: any): T }, val: any): T;
```

This is a generic function that works for any *type* `T` the caller wants.  The (unfortunately named) `type` parameter is a *constructor* object that you call with `new`, and which returns a value of type `T`.  It is an *object* that exists at runtime, not a *type* that exists only at design/compile time.

It is a confusing but useful practice to use the same name for a class constructor object and the type of an instance of the class:

```
class Foo {};
```

This creates both a class constructor object named `Foo` that exists at runtime, *and* an instance type named `Foo` that exists at design time:

```
const foo: Foo = new Foo();
```

The first `Foo` is the type, and the second `Foo` is the class constructor.  This gets transpiled into something like:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

Notice that the type named `Foo` is completely gone, since it exists only at design time.  The point is: even though you often have constructor objects with the same name as types, they are not interchangeable.  A generic type parameter is a type, not a constructor object.

---

Okay now let's see what you're passing into `create()`:

```
this.create(T, i)
```

Hmm, what's `T`?  It's the type parameter of the generic `init()` method.  So it is only the name of a design-time type, not the name of a runtime object.  This can never work.  Instead, as above, you need to pass in a constructor object of the type `{ new(p: any): T }`.  But you don't have one of those, unless you add it to the list of parameters to `init()`:

```
init<T>(ctor: { new(p: any): T }, propertyArray: T[], input: any): void {
  // ...
  this.create(ctor, i);
  // ...
}
```

Now it will compile, although you will have to pass in a constructor for `B` in your `prop` setter.  Not that I know what `B` is or if you have a constructor for it.  And not that I know why the `init()` method only does something if the `propertyArray` parameter is `null`, so that the `prop` setter can only work once.  And not that I know why you enumerate the keys of `input` and use them as arguments to whatever constructor you have for `B`.  And... well, I'm obviously confused by the rest of your code.  Suffice it to say that you need to pass in a constructor of `T` instead of `T` before you can proceed.

Hope that helps; good luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try to explain a little bit more:
I have several model objects wich are deserialized from a big JSON. And I want to populate the arrays properties using this, that's why I want a baseclass to do the job, my original set code looks like this :

`set equipments(value: any) {
    if (this._equipments == null) {
      this._equipments = [];
      for (let i in value) {
        this._equipments.push(new ReturnableEquipment(value[i]));
      }
    }
  }`